# Raspberry Pi: pip gives incompatible wheel, pip3 installs

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, wxpython

I am on a Raspberry Pi 3+ B, attempting to install things in a Python3 virtual environment. I have the wheel file `wxPython-4.0.7.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl`; when I attempt to install it using

```
sudo pip install wxPython-4.0.7.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

I get the message that the wheel file is incompatible; when I use:

```
sudo pip3 install wxPython-4.0.7.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

Now, `pip list` and `pip3 list` produce the same output, namely:

```
Package       Version
------------- -------
pip           18.1   
pkg-resources 0.0.0  
setuptools    40.8.0
```

And `pip --version` and `pip3 --version` both give:

```
pip 18.1 from /home/pi/wx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

The command `whereis pip` gives

```
pip: /usr/bin/pip /etc/pip.conf /home/pi/wx/bin/pip3.7 /home/pi/wx/bin/pip /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
```

but `whereis pip3` gives

```
pip3: /usr/bin/pip3 /home/pi/wx/bin/pip3.7 /home/pi/wx/bin/pip3 /usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz
```

My knowledge of Unix is only fair (and somewhat dated), and I'm just getting started with RPi and such. I wanted to know what implications there were for the difference between `sudo pip` and `sudo pip3`. Since I have read (on the one hand) that pip is a link for pip3, but observe here a (to me) significant difference between the two.

Comment: 1. You used `sudo pip install` and `sudo pip3 install` but `pip --version` and `pip3 --version`; you should either use `sudo` for everything or don't use `sudo` at all. 2. Well, don't use `sudo` except when you understand why it's really required; never use `sudo pip`, it's never required and could be dangerous (you're risking to upgrade system libraries and thus destroy system programs that depend on that libraries).

Comment: Are you saying that `sudo` changes the way `--version` is reported? I thought sudo had to do with the permissions with which the command is run, not the version of software being invoked. I don't know what you mean by "why it's really required", how do I know what's required of a particular installation package?

Comment: "*…`sudo` changes the way --version is reported?*" No, it changes `$PATH` and so changes what `pip` script to run thus changing what Python version is used. "*…what you mean by "why it's really required"*" Only use `sudo` for system administration tasks, not for programming. "*how do I know what's required of a particular installation package?*" That's easy — `sudo` is never required for `pip`. Always use [`virtualenv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualenv).

Comment: Historically `pip` was for `python2` and `pip3` was for `python3`. If you look at the file `pip` you should discover that it is a script. In that script will be a shebang which will tell you which python it is envoking. To discover the pip that is being run try using `which pip`, on most unix variants `which` locates a command for the current `$PATH`